# Running .exe in command prompt

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I'm trying to run an iteration program, and whenever I click on it, it opens then terminates. When I open the input text file, using the program, the iteration completes, then the window instantly closes. How can I either run it so that the window does not close (and I can see my results), or manage to do the same thing in command prompt. I'm not super familiar with doing stuff in command prompt.

Comment: open a command prompt (Start -> Run -> cmd.exe), navigate to the location of your folder using the command prompt `cd` command, run the `.exe` from there

Comment: Alternatively you can create a batch file (.bat) of two lines. First is your application's command line and the second one is "PAUSE". It will keep the command line window open 'till you press a key or close it using the "X" button. The advantage of this solution is that you can have a separate shortcut to the .bat file so you can either start your program with or without pausing at the finish.

Comment: In a command prompt, type: your_cmd.exe&&pause

Answer (score 68):

This will leave the console window open even after MyApp.exe terminates:

`cmd /K "C:\SomeFolder\MyApp.exe"`

You can create a shortcut with the above. This solution works with all console programs and does not require you to go through Command Prompt every time (or modify the original exe which you usually can't).

Incidentally the `/K` switch has been around since NT days :-p

Answer (score 20):

Another way, quite useful if the path to the .exe is a complicated one:
Start the command prompt and then just drag the .exe file into the cmd window. The full path to the file will be pasted into the prompt and you just have to press enter. No need to cd into any paths.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open command prompt -> Got to your `.exe`'s location using `cd` command -> execute your `.exe`
2. You can add `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of your code so that program will wait until the user presses some key.

Answer (score 3):

A way to run a file with cmd and have it stay open:

```
start /b /w /D"C:\StartAndEnd\scripts" NVIDIASystemMonitor.au3
```

The "/w" means it waits until the application closes.

If you are on 64bit there here is another example:

```
c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe /c c:\windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /c start /b /w /D"C:\StartAndEnd\scripts" NVIDIASystemMonitor.au3
```

This makes sure it still runs as 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

Start menu -> cmd -> cd C:\PATHTOYOURFILE\ -> program.exe

Or add a pause function at the end of your iteration program (assuming you have access to the source)

Answer (score 1):

To save the hassle of having to potentially cd into the correct folder when you're probably already there in windows explorer, simply hold shift, right click on any white space in the folder and click "Open command prompt window here" to open cmd with its directory already set. You can then just type the  name of the exe itself

Comment: This would best be entered as a *comment*, as it does not answer the original question. It is a useful tip, however.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try a redirect too.  I think this is so simple and also adds a persistence to the output message that is non-volatile.
c:\myapp.exe > c:\myapp.dbg